# Solutions of $ax \equiv k \pmod b$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Show that if $\gcd(a,b)=1$, then the congruence $ax \equiv k \pmod b$ has a solution $x$ for every integer $k$.

If $\gcd(a,b)=1$ then there exists integers $x,y$ such that $$ax+by=1,$$

then we multiply both sides by $k$ and we get $$axk+byk=k$$ which implies
$$a(xk)\equiv k \pmod b$$

This implies that the solution is $xk$. How does that look?

Comment: Perfectly fine.

Comment: You should start using more informative titles.

Comment: Minor comment is try to use different notations for $x$ since the $x$ in the question and the $x$ in the proof refers to different thing.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is essentially fine. A few tweaks from commentary.

Community wiki to show that it has been answered.

---

> Show that if $\gcd(a,b)=1$, then the congruence $ax \equiv k \pmod{b}$ has a solution $x$ for every integer $k$

*Given*  $\gcd(a,b)=1$, there must exist integers $m,n$ such that $$am+bn=1$$

Using this, we can  multiply both sides by $k$ and get 
$$\begin{align}amk+bnk &=k \\
\implies a(mk) &\equiv k\pmod{b}
\end{align}$$

This implies that we can take  $x \equiv mk \bmod b$ to satisfy the requirement.